# How to concatenate "$@" or array to one string

Tags: bash, shell, git

I am trying to implement this helper bash function:

```
ores_simple_push(){(

  set -eo pipefail
  git add .
  git add -A

  args=("$@")

  if [[ ${#args[@]} -lt 1 ]]; then
      args+=('squash-this-commit')
  fi

  git commit -am "'${args[@]}'" || { echo; }
  git push

)}
```

with: `git commit -am 'some stuff here'`, I really don't like having to enter in quotes, so I am looking to do:

```
ores_simple_push my git commit message here gets put into a single string
```

so that would become:

```
git commit -am 'my git commit message here gets put into a single string'
```

is there a sane way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Korn/POSIX-like shells, while `"$@"` expands to all the positional parameters, separated (in list contexts), `"$*"` expands to the concatenation of the positional parameters with the first character (byte with some shells) of `$IFS`¹ or with SPC if `$IFS` is unset or with nothing if `$IFS` is set to the empty string.

And in `ksh`/`zsh`/`bash`/`yash` (the Bourne-like shells with array support), that's the same for `"${array[@]}"` vs `"${array[*]}"`.

In `zsh`, `"$array"` is the same as `"${array[*]}"` while in `ksh`/`bash`, it's the same as `"${array[0]}"`. In `yash`, that's the same as `"${array[@]}"`.

In `zsh`, you can join the elements of an array with arbitrary separators with the `j` parameter expansion flag: `"${(j[ ])array}"` to join on space for instance. It's not limited to single character/byte strings, you can also do `"${(j[ and ])array}"` for instance and use the `p` parameter expansion flag to be able to use escape sequences or variables in the separator specification (like `"${(pj[\t])array}"` to join on TABs and `"${(pj[$var])array}"` to join with the contents of `$var`). See also the `F` shortcut flag (same as `pj[\n]`) to join with line-feed.

So here:

```
ores_simple_push() (
  set -o errexit -o pipefail
  git add .
  git add -A

  args=("$@")

  if [[ ${#args[@]} -lt 1 ]]; then
      args+=('squash-this-commit')
  fi

  IFS=' '
  git commit -am "${args[*]}" || true
  git push
)
```

Or just POSIXly:

```
ores_simple_push() (
  set -o errexit
  git add .
  git add -A

  [ "$#" -gt 0 ] || set square-this-commit

  IFS=' '
  git commit -am "$*" || true
  git push
)
```

With some shells (including bash, ksh93, mksh and bosh but not dash, zsh nor yash), you can also use `"${*-square-this-commit}"` here.

For completeness, in `bash`, to join arrays with arbitrary strings (for the equivalent of zsh's `joined=${(ps[$sep])array}`), you can do:

```
IFS=
joined="${array[*]/#/$sep}"
joined=${joined#"$sep"}
```

(that's assuming `$sep` is  valid text in the locale; if not, there's a chance the second step fails if the contents of `$sep` ends up forming valid text when concatenated with the rest).

---

<sup>¹ As a historical note, in the Bourne shell, they were joined with SPC regardless of the value of `$IFS`</sup>

Comment: did you really mean  `ores_simple_push()()` instead of `ores_simple_push(){()}`

Comment: I guess that works, pretty nifty!

Comment: @AlexanderMills, yes, those `{...}` are redundant. The Bourne function definition syntax is `fun() any-command` while in POSIX/bash, it's `fun() any-compound-command`. `(...)` like `{ ...; }` is a compound command.

Answer (score -1):

Actually this seems to work, but I don't know why:

```
  git commit -am "${args}" || { echo; }
```

Comment: Only in zsh with the default value of `$IFS` and when not in ksh emulation, not in ksh nor bash nor yash.

Comment: yeah i am using zsh on a new mac so makes sense

Comment: @AlexanderMills be careful with your Question tags, then - since this one currently has [tag:bash]...